# How to rollout restart deployment through the API?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes 1.15 introduced the command

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment my-deployment
```

Which would be the endpoint to call through the API?
For example if I want to scale a deployment I can call

```
PATCH /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/my-namespace/deployments/my-deployment/scale
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you dig around in the `kubectl` source you can eventually find [`(k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/polymorphichelpers).defaultObjectRestarter`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/release-1.16/pkg/polymorphichelpers/objectrestarter.go#L32).  All that does is change an annotation:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2006-01-02T15:04:05Z'
```

Anything that changes a property of the embedded pod spec in the deployment object will cause a restart; there isn't a specific API call to do it.

The useful corollary to this is that, if your `kubectl` and cluster versions aren't in sync, you can use `kubectl rollout restart` in `kubectl` 1.14 against older clusters, since it doesn't actually depend on any changes in the Kubernetes API.

Comment: Thanks very much David. I added my own annotation with a timestamp to trigger a rollout restart

Comment: Nice research @DavidMaze!

Comment: @DavidMaze but pls fix `meta` to `metadata`. As I see in the cluster, it changes this.

Comment: @LeandroCofre Can you share which endpoint(s) you called to add the annotation?

Comment: This answer is completely valid and it's the only way to trigger a rollout restart via API. After setting the date to now() I trigger a patch API on the new spec and I'm good to go.

Comment: The date in the example looks weird:  it cannot be both a `Z` date _and_ specify a timezone offset `07:00`.

Answer (score 18):

**TLDR**

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/keycloak?fieldManager=kubectl-rollout&pretty=true' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/strategic-merge-patch+json' \
--data-raw '{
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt": <time.Now()>
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

If you have `kubectl` you can debug the calls on a local minikube by providing the extra flag `--v 9` to your command.
That said you can try to do a dummy rollout restart on your local cluster to see the results.

For future readers: This can vary between versions, but if you are in `apps/v1` it should be ok.