# Kubernetes: Triggering a Rollout Restart via Configuration/AdmissionControllers

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In Kubernetes, I can trigger a rolling restart of a deployment using the `kubectl rollout` command.

```
% kubectl rollout restart deployment my-deployment-name
```

Is it possible to issue the same command via a configuration change?

More specifically, is it possible for a mutating [admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/) to trigger one of these rollouts?

I will accept answers in form of:

> Yes, here's how you do it.

or

> Yes, here's how you do it but here's why it is a Very Bad Idea™.

Comment: `kubectl rollout restart` modifies the Deployment by changing an annotation in the Pod spec template.  [How to rolling restart pods without changing deployment yaml in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559357/how-to-rolling-restart-pods-without-changing-deployment-yaml-in-kubernetes) and [How to rollout restart deployment through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050709/how-to-rollout-restart-deployment-through-the-api) both have examples of the mechanism, though not Go Kuberneten SDK code _per se_.

Comment: Yes, here is how you do it: https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Comment: @Alan Storm, Is your issue resolved? If Yes, Can you please post your resolution steps and procedure you have done for the greater visibility of the community.