# Restart pods/deployments from Kubernetes controller/operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder, kube-controller-manager

we have kubernetes deployment controller build using kubebuilder.
in controller we are updating ConfigMap in controller and then want all pods backed by deployment to restart so latest ConfigMap will be reloaded.

How can I trigger this deployment/pods restart from controller.

Note: the deployment/pod I want to restart is different form the one for which controller would have received event.

we are exploring the ways to do this

Comment: [How to rollout restart deployment through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050709/how-to-rollout-restart-deployment-through-the-api) describes what `kubectl rollout restart deployment` actually does, though not quite in Go API terms; can you adapt that?

Comment: I was thinking to have label and increment/change its value everytime and update deployment.  definitely annotation approach you suggested should also work but do you see any downside in label approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "restart" a Pod, but if the Pod is managed by a Deployment you can remove the Pod and the Deployment will spawn a new one. If you update the Deployment (e.g., by changing the name of a ConfigMap referenced in the manifest), the Deployment will automatically respawn all associated pods.

Your controller just needs to make the same API call you would normally use to delete a Pod or update a Deployment. This may require some RBAC configuration so that the ServiceAccount under which your controller is running has the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks for you input, 
We won't be able to change the ConfigMap name every time it gets updated through controller, it just not feasible in out case. 

Just wondering if I can change parameter with no functional impact in deployment and update, if that will work, what that parameter should be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; is that "can I update the deployment without triggering a restart of all pods?" (Sure, if you only update the `metadata` section) Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I want all the pods to restart, what I understand is we can do this using update api on deployment.  
I don't want to update the configmap name, then what else I can change in deployment manifest so that update api call would be successful and restarts all pods. Will having counter label in deployment and increment every time and update would work?